# My style.css file didnt work to html, when i save the file it show notepad + settings

Tags: html, css

Im just a new to html/css. when i save style.css, the file picture is notepad + settings. it didnt work in my html. what should i do?

Comment: In order to be of help, it is best to provide a minimal viable set of code that can be reviewed by the people helping.  This question doesn't provide enough detail (what doesn't work?  Is there an error?), to be able to help.   Maybe provide the snippet of HTML and the directory structure?

Comment: This icon shown in the file explorer is irrelevant. It will show the icon of the program used to edit that file. As long as the css is linked properly, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just save your file in the same folder of your HTML one. Then in your HTML code write
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` 
Now your css code should work